# Motor Shield and HC-06 Bluetooth Module competing for pins

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-motor-shield, hc-06

So my problem is this, I have an Arduino Uno with an Adafruit Motor Shield (1.0) and an HC-06 Bluetooth Module and I want to use them at the same time, the problem is that the Motor Shield uses all the ports that I need for the HC-06 (TX, RX, GND and VCC). In addition to all that, my project needs to be light weight (It's a quadcopter). Is there any way that I could use both of them at the same time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The motor shield doesn't actually use the TX and RX pins. Though as a shield it will go into all the arduino pins.

You could either solder some wires to the TX and RX pins, or use something like the [proto shield](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2077) to sandwich in the middle of it, and connect the BT module onto this shield.

You could also remove all the male headers from the motor shield, and replace them with [stacking headers](https://www.adafruit.com/products/85)

Comment: Thank you, but what about the ground pin? Could I find an alternate power supply or something?

Comment: Unlike the digital pins, you can connect multiple devices to a single Vcc or GND pin. The motor shield also has some free pads that you can use for 5v and GND (near the analog pins).

Comment: I was wondering if is not easier to just solder some stacking headers on the analog, ground and +5 area

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i had the same problem but i found like the easiest solution. So what i did was scrape the wire end to the copper using a knife or a wire cutter. And then place it in the Arduino holes and then squeeze the motor shield on top of it. Works like a charm!